# Calculate Sum of absolute difference per pixel

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, h.264, h.265

I am trying to implement a research paper just to verify my results. I have shared the code (written by me) and the description of the process given in the research paper. Unfortunately my results are a bit different from his results that means I am doing something wrong. Kindly guide me in the right direction.

**Code**

```
  fileName = 'mobile_cif.yuv';
    width=352;
    height=288;
    numFrames=30;
    SAD=0;

    %for loop to traverse & process from frame '1' to 'last' frames
    for t = 1 : numFrames
    if t < numFrames %(Need to traverse to n-1 frames)
    result=loadFileYuv(fileName,width,height,t);
    currFrame = result.cdata;    %reading Current frame
    result=loadFileYuv(fileName,width,height,t+1);
    nextFrame = result.cdata;    %reading Next frame
    % First, take the absolute value of the difference at each pixel
    myAbsDiff = abs(double(currFrame) - double(nextFrame));
    % Then, sum over all pixels
    out = sum(myAbsDiff(:));
    out=out/(width*height); %(Taking Average with respect to pixel)
    out=out/64;%(Dividing By Block size to normalize)
    disp(out);
    SAD=SAD+out;
    else
        continue;
    end

    end
    disp(SAD/numFrames);  %(Taking Average with respect to Frames)
```

**Process Description**

Sum of absolute difference (SAD) is a simple video quality metric used for block comparison and for moving vectors calculations. Each frame is divided into small blocks (i.e. 8 × 8 pixels) and for every block in one frame the most similar (minimum SAD) block in next frame is find. This minimum sum of absolutes differences is assigned as the SAD for each block in each frame (up to the n − 1 frame). Then all the SAD values are averaged for each frame and for all the frames in the clip, and divided by the block area, for normalization.

Comment: I don't see where you are dividing frame into blocks of `8x8` and calculating `SAD` for each block separately. Look into `blockproc` if you want an elegant method to do block-wise processing.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar How will I calculate SAD if I divide frame into blocks?

Comment: It is right there in the description. *Each frame is divided into small blocks (i.e. 8 × 8 pixels) and for every block in one frame the most similar (minimum SAD) block in next frame is found.* So If you have 64 blocks of 8x8 pixels in each frame, you will have 64 SADs. Then for each SAD in frame n-1, you find the closest block in terms of SAD in the frame n.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar can you help me out with this?. I don't know how to find the closest block in the next frame and then calculate SAD. I am able to divide the images in Blocks as you recommended.

Comment: If you have divided image into blocks and you also know how to calculate SAD of the entire image -> you can easily calculate SADs of each block. Now you have a 2 vectors, of length *#num_of_blocks*. Take first element in vector 1 and find its closest element in vector 2 (lookup `knnsearch` for this). Say that the index of the closest element in vector 2 corresponding to first element in vector 1 is 38, which means first block in frame n-1 is most similar to 38th block in frame n (This will never happen as it will mean there is so much motion that block 1 went to block 38 in 1/30th of a second)

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar 
`firstFrame=imread('output-1.png');
secondFrame=imread('output-2.png');
imshow(img_prev);
B = 8;         %for, 8 x 8 blocks
firstFrameBlocks = mat2cell( firstFrame, B * ones(1, size(firstFrame,1)/B), B * ones(1, size(firstFrame,2)/B), size(firstFrame,3) );
secondFrameBlocks = mat2cell( secondFrame, B * ones(1, size(secondFrame,1)/B), B * ones(1, size(secondFrame,2)/B), size(secondFrame,3) );`

Now I have take first and second frame as an Image and divided it into 8*8 blocks. Knn take both vectors how to search for a single value in knn?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113835/discussion-between-safi-mustafa-and-parag-s-chandakkar).